# Socket IO v1.4.5 disconnect issue

Tags: socket.io, client, disconnect

I'm working on socket room and i try to disconnect from client side when i refresh the page, the problem is in console i receive message that socket id is disconnected, and another socket id generated but the old socket still active

here is my code in client side :

```
    var roomSocket = io.connect("http://mysitehere.com:5001", {'forceNew': true});
var room = port;
roomSocket.on('connect', function () {
    roomSocket.emit('starting', room);
    console.log('emit connection to room');
});
roomSocket.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('connected user');
});
roomSocket.on('message', function (data) {
    console.log('Incoming message:' + data);
});
$(document).unload(function () {
    roomSocket.disconnect();
});
```

my code in server js

```
socket.on('disconnect', function (data) {
console.log('------------------------------------');
console.log("DISCONNECTION : " + socket.id);
console.log('------------------------------------');
```

});

and the result  :
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: socket should automatically disconnect when the page refreshes and it will generate a new ID every time. why do we have to disconnect manually?

Comment: becose it never remove the old socket and still make emit for all connected and disconnected sockets socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {console.log("DISCONNECTION : " + socket.id)}); try to console log on disconnect